# Update com Inner Join

Tags: mysql

Se eu fizer uma consulta do tipo *update* utilizando a cláusula *inner join*, o *update* vai afetar todos os campos que satisfaçam  a condição imposta no *inner join* ou apenas o primeiro campo?

Comment: Podes colocar um exemplo de query para ficar mais clara a pergunta?

Comment: Você pode encontrar uma solução **[aqui](https://www.somenek.com.br/somenekers/mysql/update-com-inner-join)**

Answer (score 37, accepted):

O **`UPDATE`** só será feito na coluna da tabela que você está designando, em outras palavras, só serão atualizadas as colunas com **`SET`**

### Veja o exemplo:

```
UPDATE tb1
SET tb1.column_1 = tb2.column_1
FROM table_1 AS tb1
INNER JOIN table_2 AS tb2
ON tb1.column_2 = tb2.column_3
```

---

Agora, respondendo sua pergunta, a cláusula `ON` serve para filtrar os registros em que você deseja atualizar, ou seja, olhando o exemplo, só serão atualizadas as colunas que atenderem a equivalência `ON tb1.column_2 = tb2.column_3`.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 4):

Apenas complementando a resposta já bem explicada por Rafael Gomes, pode parecer óbvio, mas acho que vale a pena ressaltar que além de ser atualizada apenas a coluna definida na cláusula SET (SET tb1.column_1 = tb2.column_1), ou seja, neste caso apenas tb1.column_1, serão atualizados TODOS os **registros** (linhas) desta coluna que satisfizerem a condição (ON tb1.column_2 = tb2.column_3).