# Query mysql no phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Boa tarde pessoal,alguém consegue me ajudar por favor?

Tenho duas tabelas, `Tabela1` e `Tabela2`, gostaria de inserir os dados da coluna `carro` da `Tabela2` na coluna `carro` da `Tabela1`, mas em seus respectivos id's, tipo, a coluna `tabela2_id` da `Tabela1` é a chave primaria da `Tabela2`.

[image: tabela1_tabela2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se isso resolve seu problema

```
update t1
   set t1.carro = t2.carro
  from tabela1 as t1
 inner join tabela2 as t2 on t2.id = t1.tabela2_id
```

Utilizei como exemplo [está resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93079/update-com-inner-join)

**EDITADO**

```
UPDATE tp531710 t1 INNER JOIN jornada as t2 on t2.id = t1.jornada_id
    SET t1.carro = t2.carro_id
  WHERE t1.carro is null
```

Comment: A query original é essa UPDATE t1
  SET t1.carro = t2.carro_id
  FROM tp531710 as t1
  INNER JOIN jornada as t2 on t2.id = t1.jornada_id

Comment: Apresentou esse erro   #1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a 'FROM tp531710 as t1
  INNER JOIN jornada as t2 on t2.id = t1.jornada_id' na linha 3

Comment: Veja se agora resolve, editei minha resposta com outra forma

Comment: Fantástico !!!! Funcionou, obrigado !